# Can't find expected json body in System.Net.WebException

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm working with an API via PowerShell that [returns human-readable errors as a json object in the response body](https://developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/errors) when an error occurs. However, when I attempt to find that json body in an exception, I can see the error, the underlying `System.Net.WebException` and the further underlying `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`, but nowhere can I find the actual body they're referring to. Is this something that is accessible?

For example, here is a valid API call that would work:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization="Token token=$YourTokenHere";"Content-type"="application/json"} -Uri "https://mydomain.pagerduty.com/api/v1/users/ABCDEF" -Body @{offset=0;limit=100}`

If you then change the user ID at the end of the URI, it fails and you get this error:

`Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization="Token token=b ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`

I can dive down in to the error to see the underlying error and the response if I do the following and convert to json for easy viewing of subproperties:
`$Error[0].Exception.Response | ConvertTo-Json`

But no matter how I comb through these errors, I can't seem to find the json body. Where might it be, or how can I capture it? I seem to have the same result if I do a try/catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the responsestream so you can get the body of the response. Ex:

```
try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization="Token token=$YourTokenHere";"Content-type"="application/json"} -Uri "https://mydomain.pagerduty.com/api/v1/users/ABCDEF" -Body @{offset=0;limit=100}
} catch {
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $json = $stream.ReadToEnd()
    $stream.Dispose()
    $json
}
```

Output:

```
{"error":{"message":"Account Not Found","code":2007}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was a stream object in there, that worked! I owe ya one.